# JQuery Conflicts with, pay per cost, Datebox, And auto station names

Tags: jquery, conflict

this is my client site http://mumbaiestatemarket.com/admin
User name: admin
Pass : admin

I was getting eror in date, calculation , and auto station names

When Auto station names is coming in textbox then... calculation and date box not coming...

This is my code:

```js
<!-- Add remove and calculation code-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   //alert('hi');
    var max_fields      = 50; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
 var input           = $(".input_field"); // input field
 var train           = $(".train_field"); // train input field
    //var add_fields      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
 var t = 1; //initial train count
    $(input).on("click",".add_field",function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(input).append('<tr><td height="40" width="300" align="center"><input style="border-radius:7px;" size="30" type="text" name="mytext[]"/></td><td align="center"><input style="border-radius:7px;" size="5" type="text" name="myage[]"/></td><td align="center"><select style="width:100px;height:22px;border-radius:7px;" name="mysex[]"><option>select</option><option>male</option><option>female</option></select></td><td ><input style="border-radius:7px;visibility: hidden;" size="30" type="text"/></td><td><input style="border-radius:7px;visibility: hidden;" size="30" type="text"/></td><td align="center"><a href="#" class="add_field" style="color:green;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;">Add</a></td><td align="center"><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="color:red;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;">Remove</a></td></tr>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(input).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    });
 
 $(train).on("click",".add_train",function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(t < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            t++; //text box increment
            $(train).append('<tr><td height="40" align="center"><input style="border-radius:7px;width:300px;" type="text" name="mytrain[]"/></td><td align="center"><input style="border-radius:7px;width:300px;" type="text" name="trainname[]"/></td><td align="center"><a href="#" class="add_train" style="color:green;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;">Add</a></td><td align="center"><a href="#" class="remove_train" style="color:red;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;">Remove</a></td></tr>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(train).on("click",".remove_train", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); t--;
    });


$('#ppc').on('change',(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('travelform'));

   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data:formData,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data){
     
     $("#tc").val(data);

     console.log("success");
     console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
     console.log("error");
     console.log(data);
    }
   });
  }));

  
  $('#ap').on('change',(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('travelform'));

   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'ajax1.php',
    data:formData,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data){
     //alert(data);
     $("#pp").val(data);

     console.log("success");
     console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
     console.log("error");
     console.log(data);
    }
   });
   
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'ajaxstatus.php',
    data:formData,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data){
     //alert(data);
     $("#st").val(data);

     console.log("success");
     console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
     console.log("error");
     console.log(data);
    }
   });
  })); 
  
  
  
});
</script>

<!--Date Code-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />
    <!-- Load jQuery JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#cal").datepicker({dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"});
  });
 </script>

<!--Station code-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
  selectFirst: true
 });
 
 $("#tag1").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
  selectFirst: true
 });
});
</script>
```

Note: When i remove Station code then Datebox and calculation of perperson working fine.

Comment: So ..... what is the question, what's not working ...... and what are we supposed to do with that wall of code ?

Comment: when i remove this station code.....

Comment: <!--Station code-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
  selectFirst: true
 });
 
 $("#tag1").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
  selectFirst: true
 });
});
</script>

Comment: Yes, it's the red button on the left, it needs to be pushed every 108 minutes ?

Comment: expect to from station is working fine date box comes and payper person calculation also works

Comment: red button is logout button... its has not relatin between

Comment: Now i found the problem... jquery.js conflict the code...  and giving problems

Comment: plz ** suggest me what to do**